# Change naming convention of CUD stored procedures in entity framework code first

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I am using EF Code First against an existing database (a.k.a "Code Second")

Many of the objects will use stored procedures for CUD operations. In code first I can specify that like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Widget>
   .MapToStoredProcedures()
```

This will assume there are stored procedures named `Widget_Insert`, `Widget_Update` and `Widget_Delete`.

If I want to use different names, I can do this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Widget>
   .MapToStoredProcedures(s => s.Insert(i => i.HasName("pr_Widget_Merge"))
                                .Update(u => u.HasName("pr_Widget_Merge"))
                                .Delete(d => .HasName("pr_Widget_Delete")));
```

My question is, using custom conventions, is there a way to tell EF what my stored procedure naming convention is so I don't have to explicitly declare each stored procedure name for each class that I want to use them?

Answer (score 1):

To change the stored procedure naming convention, you do something like the following:

```
modelBuilder.Types().Configure(c => c.MapToStoredProcedures(p => p.Update(u => u.HasName("pr_" + c.ClrType.Name + "_Merge"))));
modelBuilder.Types().Configure(c => c.MapToStoredProcedures(p => p.Insert(i => i.HasName("pr_" + c.ClrType.Name + "_Merge"))));
modelBuilder.Types().Configure(c => c.MapToStoredProcedures(p => p.Delete(d => d.HasName("pr_" + c.ClrType.Name + "_Delete"))));
```

With this, all of your entities will be mapped to stored procedures with the naming convention you specified.

Let's say that you don't want *all* of your entities to be mapped to stored procedures.  You can create an interface and implement it on entities that you want to be mapped to stored procedures.

```
public interface IMapToProcs {}
```

Then, add that interface to the entities you want stored procedures to be mapped.

```
public class Widget : IMapToProcs
```

Now, in your DbContext implementation you can do this:

```
    modelBuilder.Types().Where(t => t.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(IMapToProcs))).Configure(c => c.MapToStoredProcedures(p => p.Update(u => u.HasName("pr_" + c.ClrType.Name + "_Merge"))));
    modelBuilder.Types().Where(t => t.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(IMapToProcs))).Configure(c => c.MapToStoredProcedures(p => p.Insert(i => i.HasName("pr_" + c.ClrType.Name + "_Merge"))));
    modelBuilder.Types().Where(t => t.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(IMapToProcs))).Configure(c => c.MapToStoredProcedures(p => p.Delete(d => d.HasName("pr_" + c.ClrType.Name + "_Delete"))));
```

Finally, this can be reduced to one line:

```
    modelBuilder.Types().Where(t => t.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(IMapToProcs)))
        .Configure(c => c.MapToStoredProcedures(p => p.Update(u => u.HasName("pr_" + c.ClrType.Name + "_Merge"))
                                                      .Insert(i => i.HasName("pr_" + c.ClrType.Name + "_Merge"))
                                                      .Delete(d => d.HasName("pr_" + c.ClrType.Name + "_Delete"))));
```